# How do I remove double back slash (`\\`) from a bytes object?

Tags: python, byte, backslash

For example:

```
t = str.encode(msg)

print(t)
```

I am getting double slashes, like this:

```
b'\\xda\\xad\\x94\\xb4\\x0bg\\x92]R\\x9a1y\\x9d\\xed\\x04\\xd5\\x8e+\\x07\\xf8\\x03\\x1bm\\xd6\\x96\\x10\\xca80\\xe26\\x8a
```

But, I would like to get the result as:

```
b'\xda\xad\x94\xb4\x0bg\x92]R\x9a1y\x9d\xed\x04\xd5\x8e+\x07\xf8\x03\x1bm\xd6\x96\x10\xca80\xe26\x8a'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 19):

### Utilizing Python Text Encodings

There are text encodings that can help you get what you want both simply and easily. 
Below I encode and decode to get the desired result:

```py
# I have the string shortened for presentation
your_string = "\\xda\\xad\\x94"

your_string.encode().decode('unicode_escape').encode("raw_unicode_escape")
```

What is done above can be explained in three simple steps:

1. Encode the string in order to turn it into a `bytes` object, and to later remove the backslash escape sequences.
2. Decode the object into a string with the `unicode_escacpe` codec to unescape the backslashes.
3. Encode the object with `raw_unicode_escape` to turn it back into a bytes object without additional escaping.

**Multiple Backslash Escape Sequences**

Perhaps you have a string with multiple backslash escape sequences (or double backslashes). If so, you can just repeat steps 2 and 3 as they are listed above as many times as necessary.

```py
your_string = "\\\\xda\\\\xad\\\\x94"
your_string.encode().decode('unicode_escape').encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('unicode_escape').encode('raw_unicode_escape')
```

This could get quite tedious and messy, but you can always create a function to counter that.

**Without Backslash Escape Sequences**

Now if you have a string without any backslash escape sequences that you want to turn into a bytes object, all that is needed is the encoding seen in step 1:

```py
your_string = "\xda\xad\x94"
your_string.encode()
```

**Bytes Objects**

If you have a bytes object instead of a string, everything is basically the same, just skip step 1, because bytes objects already have an encoding (otherwise an error is raised).

```py
your_bytes_obj = b"\\xda\\xad\\x94"
your_string.decode('unicode_escape').encode("raw_unicode_escape")
```

All of these examples should grant you a bytes of object without escaped backslashes, which in the examples I have provided above is:

```py
b'\xda\xad\x94'
```

---

### Explanation

The `unicode_escape` codec removes escapes when decoding (and alternatively adds escapes when encoding), and the `raw_unicode_escape` codec does not escape backslashes when encoding. So both of these codecs come in handy when handling escape characters in bytes objects.

**raw_unicode_escape**

> Latin-1 encoding with \uXXXX and \UXXXXXXXX for other code points. Existing backslashes are not escaped in any way. It is used in the Python pickle protocol.

**unicode_escape**

> Encoding suitable as the contents of a Unicode literal in ASCII-encoded Python source code, except that quotes are not escaped. Decode from Latin-1 source code. Beware that Python source code actually uses UTF-8 by default.

I would add that the `str.encode()` method isn't the only means of encoding a string. Alternatively, you can use the `encode` function from the `codecs` module, or even the bulit-in `bytes` function (just make sure to provide for the encoding parameter).
The reason why I used the `str.encode` method here is because it seemed more straightforward.

**For more information see:**

[Python 2 Library - Python Specific Encodings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings)

[Python 3 Library - Text Encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings)

[Python 3 Lexical Analysis - String & Bytes Literals and Escape Sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)

Answer (score 4):

In Python 3.6 having you can use

```py
data_bytes, _ = codecs.escape_decode(data, 'hex')` part of `import codecs
```

library. In your case `data` is `msg` variable.

If you print the value of `data_bytes` you will get your values in bytes

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that because
    '\\'
represent a slash, not a double slash.
For example, if you will convert the msg to a string and use the print function to print the msg, you will see only one slash.

Answer (score -4):

I wanted to place this as a comment to Adrian Gherasims answer, but it got too long so I put it as a separate "answer".

For normal symbols you can use the `replace`-function

```
In [1]: temp = 'aa1aa2aa3aa4aa5'
In [2]: temp
Out[2]: 'aa1aa2aa3aa4aa5'
In [3]: temp.replace('aa', 'a')
Out[3]: 'a1a2a3a4a5'
```

However if you try to do the same with your double slash it gives a syntax error

```
In [4]: temp2 = '\\1\\2\\3\\4'
In [5]: temp2
Out[5]: '\\1\\2\\3\\4'
In [6]: temp2.replace('\\', '\')

File "<ipython-input-6-3973ee057a3e>", line 1
temp2.replace('\\', '\')
                       ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Comment: Ending this answer with how to overcome the syntax error would be much more useful.